# iterating over values inside a a key of a dict inside a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, iterator

I have the following code:

```
dict_1= {

   'key1':{'key1':[.56,.75], 'key2':[]},
   'key2':{'key1':[.76,.95], 'key2':[]},
   'key3':{'key1':[.96,1.05],'key_2':[]}
  }
  def zones_calc(ftp):
      var_1 = ftp
      for i in dict_1.iteritems():
          for v in i['key_1']:
        i[key_2.append(var_1 * v)]
zones_calc(200)
```

I keep getting an error:

```
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str
```

I am new to coding in python and I am using this as an opportunity to work with dictionaries. I have gotten this to work fine using lists and tuples, and it works fine. I am trying to utilize a dict in order to keep my multiples and results all in a dict.

What I am trying to do obviously is to multiply what is in 'key_1' and append it into 'key_2' in each of the dict keys.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are using `key_1` to lookup in your dictionary and you don't have any key in your dictionary with `key_1` value, you have multiple `key1` so I'm assuming that's what you want.

Secondly you want to indent `i[key_2.append(var_1 * v)]` and change it to something like `value['key2'].append(var_1 * v)`: again I'm assuming you want `key2` as key in your dictionaries, instead of `key_2` and you also want to fetch the value and than multiply for the var_1 value (not append something to the index of the list, that does not make any sense).

Lastly when you are iterating over dictionaries if you don't specify two values your iteration context variable will be the key of the dictionaries if you want the values you'll need something like:

`for key, value in dict_1.iteritems():`, instead of `for i in dict_1.iteritems():`.

Now If I understood correctly what you would want, this might be a solution:

```
dict_1= {

   'key1':{'key1':[.56,.75], 'key2':[]},
   'key2':{'key1':[.76,.95], 'key2':[]},
   'key3':{'key1':[.96,1.05],'key2':[]}
  }


def zones_calc(ftp):
    var_1 = ftp
    for key, value in dict_1.iteritems():
        for v in value['key1']:
            value['key2'].append(var_1 * v)

zones_calc(200)
print dict_1
```

Which outputs:

```
$ python example11.py 
{'key3': {'key2': [192.0, 210.0], 'key1': [0.96, 1.05]}, 'key2': {'key2': [152.0, 190.0], 'key1': [0.76, 0.95]}, 'key1': {'key2': [112.00000000000001, 150.0], 'key1': [0.56, 0.75]}}
```

Hope this helps.
Note that I tried to change your code in order to work, I haven't tried to make it more "pythonic".

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: understood! Thanks for the detailed explanation. I got a better grip on this now. I see now why I was getting the error. Seems I was passing the key instead of the value. And yes that was exactly what I was looking for as far as a result. The answer above uses dict,values() and also works, but this works better for me as this was just a simple example of the dict I will be using and having keys and value variables will give me flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dict_1= {
   'key1':{'key1':[.56,.75], 'key2':[]},
   'key2':{'key1':[.76,.95], 'key2':[]},
   'key3':{'key1':[.96,1.05],'key2':[]}
}

def zones_calc(ftp):
    var_1 = ftp
    for v1 in dict_1.values():
        for v in v1['key1']:
            v1['key2'].append(var_1 * v)

zones_calc(200)
```

Here's the result:

```
{'key3': {'key2': [192.0, 210.0], 'key1': [0.96, 1.05]},
 'key2': {'key2': [152.0, 190.0], 'key1': [0.76, 0.95]},
 'key1': {'key2': [112.00000000000001, 150.0], 'key1': [0.56, 0.75]}}
```

The fractional portion on the last line is due to floating point roundoff:

```
>>> 0.56 * 200
112.00000000000001
>>>
```